# Подключение бд к сайту

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Как подключить MySql Workbench 8.0 CE к сайту(нужен для регистрации и авторизации) Могу использовать для создания и управления бд MySQL Workbench; MySQL for Visual Studio; Connector/NET; Connector/ODBC; Connector/Python. Расскажите пожалуйста подробнее, заранее благодарен.

Comment: MySql Workbench- это не БД, а клиент к базе данных. БД для сайта выдает хостинг провайдер, надо обратиться к нему по поводу подключения

Comment: А если никто ничего не выдал? Можно ли создать бд из того ПО , которое я перечислил, а потом подключить это к сайту?

Comment: Нет. из того что ты перечислил - нельзя. Из того которое есть на сайте - скорее всего можно. Но с таким уровней знаний лучше обратиться, чтобы выдали. Пароль тебе в любом случае нужен будет

Comment: Из того которое есть на сайте? О чём вы?

Comment: О сайте. К которому надо подключить БД